# select rows from table in ios

Tags: ios, uitableview, row, selection

i am new to xcode, i am using this code for selecting 10 rows from my table maximum. this code is working but there is a problem with it that suppose when i select one row from it, then automatically some other values are selected with my selection. i dont understand what kind of error this is please help me to remove this error. THANKYOU

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
 UITableViewCell *selectedCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
if ([selectedCell accessoryType] == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone) {
    if(count < 10)
    {
        [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
        [selectedobjects addObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
        count++;
    }

} else {
    [selectedCell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    [selectedobjects removeObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:indexPath.row]];
    count --;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is due to the cell reuse. You need to check the selected cell in ***cellForRowAtIndexPath*** and give the accessory type accordingly. Its is better to save the indexPath of the selected item in ***didSelectRowAtIndexPAth*** instead of `indexPath.row` as `selectedObject`. Then do

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

  // Do other stuff
  if ([selectedobjects containsObject:indexPath]) {
    [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
  }
  else
   {
     [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
   }
}
```

Comment: i did it same, but when i started scrolling ma table towards downwards and when i came back the row which i have selected automatically deselected.. :(

Comment: if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    // Do other stuff
    if ([selectedobjects containsObject:indexPath]) {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryNone];
    }
       cell.textLabel.text = [myArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]; //=@"ASDF" works.
    return cell;

Comment: Are u sure you put the code outside of if(cell == nil) and your selectedObjects contains selected indexPaths

Answer (score 0):

take one NSMutable Dictionary in  u r .h  dn't do any properties and synthesize for Dictionary.

Use this line in CellForRowAtIndex

```
if([tickmarkDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[indexPath row]]])
{
    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
}
```

and Use the DidSelectRowAtIndex method as below.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *thisCell= (UITableViewCell *) [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (thisCell.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryNone)
    {
        thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

        [tickmarkDictionary setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",thisCell.textLabel.text] forKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[indexPath row]]];
    }
    else
    {
        if([tickmarkDictionary objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d$%d",[indexPath section],[indexPath row]]])
        {
          [tickmarkDictionary removeObjectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",[indexPath row]]];

        }
        NSLog(@"dict count %d",[tickmarkDictionary count]);
        thisCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
    }

     NSLog(@"dict count %d",[tickmarkDictionary count]);
}
```

Now,when You started scrolling Your table upwards and  downwards and when You came back to the row which You have selected automatically will not deselected.

Try this once.I hope it helps u.